# Wiener-Hopf equation

Tags: adaptive-filters

The Wiener-Hopf is given by

$$\mathbf W_\text{opt} = \mathbf R^{-1} \mathbf P$$

- What if the matrix $\mathbf R$ is almost singular?
- When $\mathbf R$ is singular, the inverse of $\mathbf R$ does not exist, 
  what modification can I do to make it usable?

My idea is move the $\mathbf R$ to the left side of the equation, is that right?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you're referring to – the Wiener-Hopf equation doesn't easily break down to the equation you use, so you're probably in a special case of one of these. I think you'll need to add a lot more context. What is $W$, what is $R$, what is $P$? Without you defining those, they are essentially just letters (ok, you tell us R is a matrix)

Comment: Sorry about that, all symbols have their usual meanings.  Like X(n) is given signal d(n) denote the desired response or target output for the filter, R is correlation matrix of X(n) and P is the cross-correlation vector between d(n) and X(n).

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include that info. These might be "usual meanings" for you, but you can't presume we know in which context you operate. Also, you didn't even mention d(n) in your question, and also, it doesn't seem to be a usual symbol, at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you refer to the [Wiener-Hopf equation in discrete time for FIR filters.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter#Finite_impulse_response_Wiener_filter_for_discrete_series). If this is a homework-task, then I guess most probably you did some mistake in calculation of $R$ (e.g. if you have white noise in the signal, you wont have a singular $R$).

Anyway, there are some methods to solve this:

1. You dont necessarily need the inverse of $R$. You need a solution to the problem $RW_{opt}=P$, which leads to $W_{opt}=R^{-1}P$ in case $R$ is regular. However, if $R$ is singular, it may still happen, that $P$ is in the image of $R$. Then, still you can find $W_{opt}$ as the solution to the equation $RW_{opt}=P$.
2. (this is just an approximate solution): If you have a singular $R$, you can replace the equation by $W_{opt}=(R+\alpha I)^{-1}P$, i.e. add some regularization factor to the matrix. This will make the system well-defined, but it will not correspond to the exact solution. Note, that in case $R$ is singular and $P$ is not in its image, then there is no exact solution.
3. You can go for the [pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $R$. BUt again, this will not correspond to an exact solution, as it does not exist.

All in all, if your $R$ is singular, something is really bad in your model I believe.